# Place logo on Top layer in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium

I use the "PCB Logo Creator" script to convert my BMP logo and import it into the top layer. It works well. But I don't want to do this "conversion" every time, so I made the generated logo to a part in my components library, then I can place the part in the schematic, and it will be automatically placed on the PCB.

The problem is, because the generated "logo" are composed of many "lines", and the lines are 1mil thin, it's less than my width constraint, so it throw many "DRC" errors.

Of course, I can lower my width constraint to less than 1mil, but it seems so "brute". I wonder, what's the most "elegant" and easy method to put my logo onto the PCB without many tricks?

Any suggestion?

Comment: If your logo is a block you can save it with wider traces. So, when your design is ready you resize it...

Comment: What do you mean 'block'? There are hundreds of lines, and if I change their width as whole, my logo will be fatter, right?

Comment: Sure. But if you will resize it after run the DRC it will not be a problem, right?

Comment: I have wonder if you can add a specific design rule which allows 1mil tracks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the wrong way to go. What you should do is the following:

- Use a font creator tool to generate a custom font in TTF format (e.g. Font Creator)
- One of the characters is your logo in a vectorized format
- Then use a string field on your PCB and type one character (which stands for your font)
- Select your font and you should see it being displayed nicely.

For an example look at the "[Mooretronic](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Board+Implementation+-+FAQs)" font. This font contains symbols for all kinds of stuff (ESD protection, Logos, ...).

We do designs for various customers and have a font with all their logos so we can just select which one we need. This way, it's also easy to remove soldermask on top of it so the gold surface can shine through (sorry, don't know how to explain that in english :-) )

Answer (score 1):

I use the same script, and my experience is that although the logo doesn't look that great in Altium, when it is produced it looks all right, because the silk manufacturing is not that precise so it smooths the lines. So I would go ahead with that method, you don't have to go lower than 1mil.

Answer (score -1):

The problem would be when you try to manufacture a lot of tiny mil wide lines in silk or copper. They won't be able to do that. 
You should change your logo, as suggested, so that it's "filled in" rather than a lot of small lines, so that you can use a few thick lines rather than many small lines.

Or, use a sticker after the fact.